# Are there any javascript libs to detect an image with the webcam? And if yes then proceed to a function?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, match, tracking, detection

I'm looking for a tracking system that detect a form with the help of a webcam. I tried Tracking.js that can do that on a static pictures or only detect pictures and color with the help of the webcam... Which is great but tough to modify.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. asking for library recommendations are off topic.

Comment: You might try to ask this question at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can try opencv.js. It's a little complicated, but powerful.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d2/d99/tutorial_js_face_detection.html